# How to add multiple style placeholder input

Tags: html, css

Hello is that possible to multiple style **placeholder** in 1 input, maybe this image can help my expected

[image]

i have another solution to make like this but not use placehodler, but i still curios is have way **placeholder** multiple style in one input :)